# How to create multiple filters params using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have to create this type of filters https://www.vroom.com/catalog/all-years/acura_ilx,bmw/?price_min=20000&price_max=30000&miles_max=20000 in my website any suggestions how to do with react-router-dom params and query strings but the issue is when I set the optional params in the Route path or URL it will replace the previous filters i have many filters in my website

Comment: The question is unclear. What are you trying to do? You want to generate the URL as mentioned in the question or you want to route the requests as per URL mentioned?

Comment: yes I just want to create url like this.because when I go to this link it will get params values and then filter it

Comment: but the issue is when I set the optional params in the Route path or URL it will replace the previous filters i have many filters in my website